# regex matching and substring extraction

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression

I have these files, manually created by many different people are coming in. Formatting, although following a certain rule, is not uniform.

think of these three lines below

```
"erroneous_data_F08R16_recordeded_by_tech21"
"erroneous_data_F8R16_recordeded_by_tech021"
"erroneous_data_F008R016_recordeded_by_tech21"
```

they all point to the same thing
F008 or F08 or F8 means File number 8 
R16 or R016 or (R[single-digit] where possible) means Row number 16

There are any number of these lines in a given file, which will be scanned using `while read line` loop.

What I want to do is to make the File and Row number section uniform, such as F008R016 for the above three lines of examples, as my file numbers are no more than 3 digits (it rolls over after reaching 999 and number of lines is never more than a handful in each file, but for the sake of consistency, lets say it is 3 digits. In this file I need to process, there also exists unstructured comments. So first order of business is detecting the lines and separating them in to a different temporary file, then making them uniform.

In order to accomplish this, my plan is to echo the line and grep for regex matching the pattern. Unfortunately, regex is not my strong point.

So far I am stuck at detection of the file#row# structure in the line

```
cat InputFile | while read line
do
  echo $line | grep '[F,f]\d\d[R,r]\d\d' >/dev/null  #this is assuming two digit file number and 2 digit row number 
  result=$?
  if [ $result -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo $line >tempfile
  fi
done
```

this regex matching on the grep command fails all the time, even if the line contains F08R16 pattern.

After accomplishing this, I want to extract this substring into a variable and analyze the structure of the variable and add leading zeros where necessary to make it uniform.

Any suggestions to correct my regex and accomplish my higher goal of extracting into variable, is greatly appreciated.

For what it is worth, I am working on a CentOS release 6.7 box at the time but I have other distros at my disposal.

Comment: Your 3 lines of sample data are FnnRnn, but your grep regex has SnnEnn; is one of them wrong? Otherwise, that's why you're not matching.

Comment: are you trying to match a comma? and i don't think `\d` means anything. match `[0-9]`.

Comment: Sorry I copied that line from an online regex builder web page and modified them on my Linux box. But did not reflect the changes here. Now it is corrected and still not matching. I tried single quotes and double quotes on the grep's matching string but result was no different

Comment: @mikeserv: that pattern I am trying to match, came from an oline regex builder. Not from my knowledge.

Comment: I'd suggest a whole different approach - perhaps a `perl` one-liner using `sprintf` with suitable zero-padded formats for the digits

Comment: @Scott the `\d` doesn't mean anything in BRE (grep's default regex flavor) try `grep -E` or `grep -P` instead. Also, do you _need_ to do this in the shell? It is much simpler and far, far faster if you use another language instead.

Comment: @steeldriver I am all ears for the suggestion but my perl knowledge is equally bad if not worse, compared to regex building

Comment: @terdon unfortunately it has to be done in shell.

Comment: Well it depends what else is in the file, but it could be something as simple as `perl -pe 's/_F(\d+)R(\d+)_/sprintf "_F%03dR%03d_",$1,$2/e' file` I think (my perl is marginal at best)

Comment: @Scott why? Why would the loop need to be in shell? You are already using non-shell tools so I don't see why the loop would need to be done in the shell. Post another question explaining the entire procedure and we can give you a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

I will assume you want to match an `f` or an `F`, then 1, 2 or 3 numbers followed by an `r` or `R` and then 1, 2 or 3 numbers again until a `_`. If so, you can do (with GNU `grep`):

```
grep -iP 'f\d{1,3}r\d{1,3}_' InputFile > tmpfile
```

Or, with non-GNU `grep`:

```
grep -iE 'f[0-9]{1,3}r[0-9]{1,3}_' InputFile > tmpfile
```

However, this is almost certainly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You really don't want to be doing this sort of thing in the shell. For example, this `perl` one-liner will format all the relevant lines correctly:

```
$ perl -pe 's/_f(\d+)r(\d+)_/sprintf("_F%03dR%03d_",$1,$2)/ei' file
"erroneous_data_F008R016_recordeded_by_tech21"
"erroneous_data_F008R016_recordeded_by_tech021"
"erroneous_data_F008R016_recordeded_by_tech21"
```

That's just to give you an idea of the sort of tricks you can use to avoid this type of issue.

Answer (score 2):

Don't `echo` it into `grep` like that - that's crazy.

```
<infile grep -iE '([fr][0-9]+){2}' >outfile
```

...should get you the lines you're asking about. Calling `cat` to write a file to your shell over a pipe that you then `read` byte for byte which you then copy out over another pipe after interpreting and eliding various shell syntax characters with `echo` byte for byte so that you can silently `grep` those bytes for success... well...

`grep` will just write the matches out to you. If you want a count of matching lines or something use `-c`. If you want the line numbers for matching lines use `-n`.  If you want case-insensitive matches use `-i`. Maybe try `man grep` for more.

To live-edit the stream you might use `sed`:

```
sed -Ee:t -e's/((_)[Ff]|[0-9]{3,}[Rr])([0-9]{1,2}(\2|[Rr]))/\10\3/g;tt'
```

You'll need a GNU/BSD/AST `sed` for that to work. But it works pretty well:

```
sed -Ee:t -e's/((_)[Ff]|[0-9]{3,}[Rr])([0-9]{1,2}(\2|[Rr]))/\10\3/g;tt' \
<<""
"erroneous_data_F08R16_recordeded_by_tech21"
"erroneous_data_F8R16_recordeded_by_tech021"
"erroneous_data_F008R016_recordeded_by_tech21"
```

---

```
"erroneous_data_F008R016_recordeded_by_tech21"
"erroneous_data_F008R016_recordeded_by_tech021"
"erroneous_data_F008R016_recordeded_by_tech21"
```

You're not the first guy to come here complaining about that tech 21, either. Somebody should straighten that guy out.

Answer (score 0):

terdon's `perl` answer is certainly elegant, and I agree:
if the goal is to make all the data formatted uniformly/consistently,
there's no need to separate out the lines need to be changed. 
In case you don't like `perl`
(or in the unlikely event that you don't have it),
here's a `sed` solution:

```
sed -re 's/_[Ff]([0-9]+)[Rr]([0-9]+)_/_F00\1R00\2_/' \
                                          -e 's/_F0*([0-9]{3})R0*([0-9]{3})_/_F\1R\2_/'
```

This can be typed as all one line
(leave out the `\` at the end of the first line). 
I admit, this is not as elegant as the `perl` solution. 
It works in two steps:

- Add `00` after every `F` or `R` (or `f` or `r`) in the 
  `_ F file_number R file_number _` 
  pattern. 
  This changes single-digit `8` to `008`, double-digit `08` to `0008`,
  and triple-digit `008` to `00008`.
  (The first step also capitalizes `f` or `r`.)
- After every `F` or `R` in the 
  `_ F file_number R file_number _` 
  pattern, delete however many zeroes appear before the last three digits. 
  So `008` is left alone, while `0008` and `00008` are changed to `008`.

If your version of `sed` doesn't support the `-r` (use extended regular expressions) option, use

```
sed -e 's/_[Ff]\([0-9]*\)[Rr]\([0-9]*\)_/_F00\1R00\2_/' \
                                          -e 's/_F0*\([0-9]{3}\)R0*\([0-9]{3}\)_/_F\1R\2_/'
```

using `\(…\)` instead of `(…)` and `*` instead of `+`. 
(`*` and `+` don't mean the same thing,
but they're close enough in this case, unless there are lines with strings like `_FR42_` or `_F17R_`. 
In fact, you could use `*` instead of `+` in the first command, too.)

#### How to use these

- `sed option(s) scripts   InputFile`
  or
  `sed option(s) scripts < InputFile`
  to process the input file and see the results on the screen.
- `sed option(s) scripts   InputFile > output_file`
  or
  `sed option(s) scripts < InputFile > output_file`
  to process the input file and send the results to a new file.
- `sed -i option(s) scripts InputFile`
  to process the file and modify it in-place;
  i.e., send the results back into the original file.